# Equalities in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, equality

In C++, the usual way of determining if some value, x, is between two limits is to:

```
  //This is (A)
double x = 0.0d;
double lower = -1.0d;
double upper = +1.0d;

if(x > lower && x < upper){
  // Do some stuff
}
```

But today I discovered by accident that I can do this:

```
  // This is (B)
double x = 0.0d;
double lower = -1.0d;
double upper = +1.0d;

if(lower < x < upper){
  // Do some stuff
}
```

It seems to work fine, but I've never heard of this being done before, with "lower < x < upper". Does this produce executable code as you would expect it to? IE, is (A) equivalent to (B)?

I think a lot of people won't know about this, and I suspect that might be because the compiler interprets (A) differently to (B). It this right?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, A and B are *not* equivalent, you cannot do this.

Or, obviously you *can* (as you discovered) but you're not doing what you think you're doing.

You're evaluating `(lower < x) < upper`, i.e. the value of `lower < x` (which is `false` or `true`, but which convert to `int` for the comparison) is compared to `upper`.

See [this table of operator precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++#Operator_precedence) for more information.

Comment: Ah! Thank you, I thought it might be something like that!

Answer (score 3):

They are definitely not equivalent. Your expression `lower < x < upper` will first evaluate `lower < x` to either true or false, and then do `true < x` or `false < x` respectively.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it evaluates `lower < x` to either `1` or `0`, not `true` or `false`.

Comment: @egrunin: In C++ is `true` or `false`, which are implicitly convertible to `1` or `0`

Comment: @egrunin "The operators < (less than), > (greater than), <= (less than or equal to), and >= (greater than or equal to) all yield `false` or `true`."

Comment: @K-ballo : look at `unwind`'s answer for the correct phrasing.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work fine. In fact, it's dead wrong, and only works by accident.

`lower < x < upper` is parsed as `(lower < x) < upper`; `(lower < x)` has type `bool`, and its value is either `true` or `false`, depending on the value of `x`. To compare that `bool` value to `upper` the compiler converts the bool to a float with the value `1.0` for `true` and `0.0` for `false`.

Answer (score -3):

Well, yes. In either cases `x` is between the value range.
For example:
    lower = 4;
    upper = 9;
    x = 7;

If you do: `7 > 4 && 7 < 9` is the same as saying `4 < 7 < 9`.
This is basic arithmetics, by the way.

Comment: It's basic arithmetic, but it's not basic C or C++. `4 < 7 < 9` is true because `4 < 7` is true, and `true < 9` is also `true`. But `7 < 4 < 9` is also `true`.

Comment: No it's wrong. Itis basic arthmentic, but C++ `<` and `>` are not "*arthmentic*": they follow another kind of associativuty